# GZipStream decompress only 4kb of data

Tags: c#, gzip

Why GZipStream, based on MemoryStream reads from it only 24576bytes and cant read any further? I compress my gz with multithreading, in parts, but winrar could decompress it and GZipStream not.

```
        static private bool ZipperWork2(string InputPath, string OutputPath, CompressionMode CompMode)
    {
        Mode = CompMode;
        RawData = new byte[ThreadCount][];
        CompressedData = new byte[ThreadCount][];
        Thread[] CompressorThreads = new Thread[ThreadCount];
        byte[] buffer = new byte[MAX_BLOCK_SIZE];

        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(InputPath, FileMode.Open))
        {
            using (FileStream fw = new FileStream(OutputPath, FileMode.Append))
            {
                while (fs.Position < fs.Length)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < ThreadCount; i++)
                    {
                        int count = fs.Read(buffer, 0, MAX_BLOCK_SIZE);
                        RawData[i] = new byte[count];
                        Array.Copy(buffer, RawData[i], count);
                        CompressorThreads[i] = new Thread(WorkWithBlock2);
                        CompressorThreads[i].Start(i);
                    }
                    for (int i = 0; i < ThreadCount; i++)
                    {
                        CompressorThreads[i].Join();
                        fw.Write(CompressedData[i], 0, CompressedData[i].Length);
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    private static void WorkWithBlock2(object index)
    {
        int DataIndex = (int)index;
        //int count=0,totalcount=0;

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(RawData[DataIndex]))
        {
            using (MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (GZipStream gz = new GZipStream(ms, Mode))
                {
                    gz.CopyTo(output);
                }
                CompressedData[DataIndex] = output.ToArray();
            }
        }
 }
```

I trying to do it in a different ways, but result are always the same, decompress only 4KB (and it don't relate with my MAX_BLOCK_SIZE variable)

Comment: What is the value of `count`? Where does `RawData` come from? What do you expect this code to do? Why do you start a new thread after every read?

Comment: This code must decompress gz from file fs and save it to fw (yes, i know names are not appropriated). For that i creating 4 threads (in my case) and start decompress blocks. Count - number of read bytes from source.

Comment: Your approach won't work - the combined result will not be a valid zip stream and  unless you save information which parts were written by which Thread / stream, you won't be able to decompress the data you wrote

Comment: You don't have to quote the documentation on me, I know what Stream.Read() returns. I mean that you need to check it in your code. This code also cannot work, you cannot start decompressing compressed data mid-stream. You cannot decompress multi-threaded like this.

Comment: how do I decompress at least with simplest way (with GZipStream on source and copyto output)? It's still 4kb on output, but how winrar manage this? My gz file contains multiple gz headers, but somehow winrar emerge it in one...

Answer (score 2):

Your gzip stream may actually consist of multiple concatenated gzip streams.  This is permitted by the gzip format.  `GZipStream` is likely just reading the first one.  All you'd need to do is repeat the operation on the subsequent input bytes until all of the input bytes have been consumed.

Comment: is there any way to "pull" gZipStream to next block? How can i do it in a better way?

Comment: I'm in desperate, please tell me how to work with multipart gzip files, i cant find anything useful

Comment: Just put another `while` loop outside what you have and repeat until you run out of input data.

Comment: But I dont know block size, so, Stream reads, for example, 4kb, where on position 3567 was beginning of next block and GZip crashes. Am i doing something wrong?